# How can i optimise this query, $ememMatch taking a lot more time to execute

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

how can i make execution more faster, following query is taking 3.3 seconds to execute from 55,000 records, as per me the `$elemMatch` is taking more time, without that condition it executes in milliseconds. please help me to find the way to make it more faster.

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([{
        "$match": {
            "is_expired": false,
            "is_completed": true,
            "is_deleted": false,
            "$and": [{
                "$or": [{
                    "reported_abusive": {
                        "$ne": true
                    }
                }, {
                    "created_by": ObjectId("5ac6123e385e6a58669d8b06")
                }]
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "$sort": {
            "time_frame.end_on": 1
        }
    }, {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "dburst",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "dbursts.t_id",
            "as": "dburst"
        }
    }, {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "sburst",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "t_id",
            "as": "sburst"
        }
    }, {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [{
                "created_by": ObjectId("5ac6123e385e6a58669d8b06")
            }, {
                "sburst": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "shared_with": {
                            "$elemMatch": {
                                "user_id": ObjectId("5ac6123e385e6a58669d8b06"),
                                "is_dbursted": false,
                                "is_deleted": false
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, {
                "dburst": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "user_id": ObjectId("5ac6123e385e6a58669d8b06")
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "$skip": 0
    }, {
        "$limit": 10
    }])
```

Comment: @Veeram can yo please help me here.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet there is one case where i can't use $lookup with pipeline,

{
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "dburst",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "dbursts.t_id",
            "as": "dburst"
        }
    }

Comment: what's that case?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I've used lookup with sub document of other collection